# Xampp not running due to PHP 7

Tags: php, apache, xampp, php-7

Yes, I have read other topics saying to uninstall skype (I do not have skype), and to change port '80' to '8080' in config file - none of this worked for me.

My problem started when I downloaded PHP version 7 (till now I used 5.3 I guess). I've deleted everything from my xampp/php folder, and unzipped there PHP 7 files.

My Xampp apache control panel doesn't start and displays:

```
Apache]     Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
13:40:33  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
13:40:33  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
13:40:33  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
13:40:33  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
13:40:33  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
13:40:33  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

What can cause the problem? What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

From here you can download the XAMPP with PHP 7
https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html